# How to handle data frame column value "NA", Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have imported csv file having columns "Country", "Commodity", "Attribute", "Value" to dataframe.
"Country" having value "NA" and dataframe considers as blank.

Then I am updating it '"NA"'

```
data['Country_Code'].fillna('"NA"', inplace=True)
```

Then I do some calculation in data, finally will export entire file.

For Country '"NA"', I will remove " manually from the exported file.

How to export '"NA"' as NA, I don't want to do manually as file contains 2millions of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need parameter `na_rep='NA'` in [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and remove `fillna`.

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[np.nan,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,np.nan,4,2,3]})

print (df)
   A    B    C
0  a  NaN  7.0
1  b  5.0  8.0
2  c  4.0  NaN
3  d  5.0  4.0
4  e  5.0  2.0
5  f  4.0  3.0

#test output
print (df.to_csv(na_rep='NA'))
,A,B,C
0,a,NA,7.0
1,b,5.0,8.0
2,c,4.0,NA
3,d,5.0,4.0
4,e,5.0,2.0
5,f,4.0,3.0
```

For write to file:

```
df.to_csv('file', na_rep='NA', index=False)
```

You can also use parameter `keep_default_na` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), but then all data are `strings`, not floats.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file', keep_default_na=False)
print (df)
   A    B    C
0  a   NA  7.0
1  b  5.0  8.0
2  c  4.0   NA
3  d  5.0  4.0
4  e  5.0  2.0
5  f  4.0  3.0

print (df.dtypes)
A    object
B    object
C    object
dtype: object
```

By default `NA` is read as `NaN`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file')
print (df)
   A    B    C
0  a  NaN  7.0
1  b  5.0  8.0
2  c  4.0  NaN
3  d  5.0  4.0
4  e  5.0  2.0
5  f  4.0  3.0

print (df.dtypes)
A     object
B    float64
C    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: na_rep='NA' while exporting right?, is there any parameter to pass while importing in pd.read_csv

Comment: Yes, but default `NA` will be read as `NaN`. But if need some another string, need set it by [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#na-values).